# Assignment of references in Rust

Tags: rust

The following code doesn't compile, because `x` is used after move (since `x` has type `&mut u8`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait)

```
fn main() {
    let mut a: u8 = 1;
    let x: &mut u8 = &mut a;
    let y = x;
    x;
}
```

And as I understand `y` implicitly has type `&mut u8`

But if I specify the type of `y` explicitly it compiles. The following code compiles

```
fn main() {
    let mut a: u8 = 1;
    let x: &mut u8 = &mut a;
    let y: &mut u8 = x;
    x;
}
```

By the way if I change `let y: &mut u8 = x;` to `let y: &u8 = x;` it also compiles.

It seems to me nothing has changed, `y` is `&mut u8` in the first example and it is `&mut u8` in the second but the former doesn't compile and the latter does compile.

Why? What's the difference?

Comment: `"And as I understand y implicitly has type &mut u8"` I don't have a IDE in front of me at the moment but I think this is wrong, the type of y is `&u8`.

Comment: `let y: &u8 = x;` also compiles

Comment: I was wrong then. Can you give me the error message?

Comment: `error[E0382]: use of moved value: `x``

Comment: link to rust playground [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=89ea4e1a5686cc584870f16e47c17603)

Comment: I expect that this is re-borrowing at play; that is, that somehow specifying the type of `y` changes the fact that `x` is moved to `x` being re-borrowed instead (with a shorter lifetime) and since `y` is not used, the re-borrow ends immediately and `x` becomes usable again. I've got no idea why, however...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&mut u8` is not a complete type. All reference types must have a lifetime parameter on them. When you elide it, the Rust compiler must infer it, and it will pick the shortest lifetime possible. In your first example, the first step of desugaring is (using [a fake syntax from the Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetimes.html)):

```
fn main() {
    let mut a: u8 = 1;
    'a: {
    let x: &'a mut u8 = &'a mut a; // the lifetime of x must last until it's use at the end
    let y = x;
    x;
    }
}
```

This is still not completely explicit, since the type of `y` is still not known. What is it? Well, since it's being assigned from `x`, which is a `&'a mut u8`, it should also be a `&'a mut u8`. Note that this is *not* following the "shortest lifetime possible" rule of lifetime elision. You didn't elide a lifetime, you elided the whole type, which is reconstructed by type inference.

```
fn main() {
    let mut a: u8 = 1;
    'a: {
    let x: &'a mut u8 = &'a mut a; // the lifetime of x must last until its use at the end
    let y: &'a mut u8 = x;
    x;
    }
}
```

Well, that's no good. Since `y` has the same lifetime as `x`, its creation involves moving the reference in `x` and making `x` invalid. The program is thus rejected for trying to use `x`.

Adding the signature to `y` essentially gives the compiler a new place where it can infer lifetimes. Before, normal type inference made `y` have the same type as `x`, which meant it lasted as long as `x` and made `x` unusable. Now, `y` *doesn't* need to have the same type as `x`; the lifetime of the borrow can be different. In particular, it is made shorter.

```
fn main() {
    let mut a: u8 = 1;
    'a: {
    let x: &'a mut u8 = &'a mut a; // the lifetime of x must last until it's use at the end
    'b: {
    let y: &'b mut u8 = x; // y and x can now have different lifetimes, *x is reborrowed here
    }
    x; // x not moved from, still valid
    }
}
```

Now, instead of moving the reference `x` into `y` and making it invalid, the value `*x` is temporarily "reborrowed" to make `y`, as by `let y: &'b mut u8 = &'b mut *x`.

The other possible fix is to explicitly say "borrow `*x` again with a different lifetime":

```
fn main() {
    let mut a: u8 = 1;
    let x: &mut u8 = &mut a;
    let y = &mut *x;
    x;
}
```

The principle is the same as before: saying `&` more often gives the compiler more places where it can massage the lifetimes in the program to make everything work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please also briefly answer, don't we have two mutable references to `a` at once here? Is this explained by lifetimes as well? So we have one borrower `x`, then only one borrower `y` and then again `x`?

Comment: I don't think that's explained by lifetimes, no. The borrow checker tracks that `a` is borrowed by `x`, then by `y`, then by `x` again, but I don't believe this is actually written into the lifetimes. Not sure though.